# Php artisan schedule:run only once execute command in localhost

Tags: laravel-5, command, scheduled-tasks

I created a command artisan to make a text file in my path. This command executes correctly by running the command but not for task scheduling in my localhost (not server).

**CreateFile class**:

```
protected $signature = 'create:file';

public function handle()
{
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "parisa";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

**Kernel.php**:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\CreateFile::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('create:file')->everyMinute();
}
```

When I run `php artisan schedule:run` my command executes only once at that moment. But I want to execute every minute. How to fix it?

Comment: To run scheduler in background you should hit command `php artisan schedule:work`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally